# Solve $f''(x) - f'(2x) - f(x) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve a problem and fall into that differential equation. I'm curious because I couldn't find a way to solve it.
What can work to solve it?

Comment: I would try a Laplace transform, though I don't expect this to have a nice solution.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I don't have much practice with this type of solution. But I still made some attempts, even though without much success.

Comment: Differential equations with varying function arguments rarely have nice solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my attempt:

The first thing we can see is that this equation describes the kernel of the linear operator $L : C^{\infty} ( \Bbb R ) \to C^{\infty} ( \Bbb R )$
$$Lf(x)=f''(x) - f'(2x)-f(x)$$
In other words the space of solutions is a vector space. In particular $f(x)=0$ is a trivial solution.

Now, suppose $f(x)$ is analytic at $x=0$, and write
$$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$
Then the equation becomes
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ((n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} - (n+1)a_{n+1}2^n - a_n )x^n=0$$
Hence for all $n$ we need
$$(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} - (n+1)a_{n+1}2^n - a_n =0$$
which can be written as a recursive sequence for all $n \ge 0$
$$a_{n+2}= \frac{(n+1)a_{n+1}2^n + a_n}{(n+2)(n+1)}$$
Clearly here $a_0$ and $a_1$ are free (they can be anything). Hence the space of solutions has dimension 2.

HOWEVER there is a problem:

Assuming $a_0, a_1 \ge 0$, one can compute the radius of convergence; indeed:
$$a_{n+2} = \frac{(n+1)a_{n+1}2^n + a_n}{(n+2)(n+1)} \ge \frac{a_{n+1}2^n }{(n+2)}$$
And so
$$\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}} \ge \frac{2^n }{(n+2)} \to \infty$$
this means that the radius of convergence is zero: we have no function at all.

Here my attempt concludes. My suspect is that there is no solution other than the trivial zero function.